# How to bypass Active X pop-ups when a html file with active x controls are loaded in IE+6

Tags: javascript, html, vb6, activex

i have a vb6 project which uses web-components to open a HTML file, whenever i execute the vb6 program it asks me "Active X control on this page might be unsafe to interact with other parts of the page.Do you want to allow this interaction? Yes or No"

How to bypass this pop up?

Comment: modified question due to broken link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make your OCX safe for scripting, then this problem will go away (but I guess from your other question, you already know this).